# Do MySQL clusters 7.5 CGE supports TDE for the NDB storage engine?

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, innodb

I'm looking for in-built TDE support for MySQL clusters CGE edition.

My requirement is to have facility to encrypt specific tables in NDB engine and should be transparent to the application also.

Kindly advise.

Comment: What good is encryption if a hacker can get the application to decrypt it?

Comment: No good. But at-least we can prevent the application data from being accessed externally from the DB file.